# How can I start SwiftUI Slider's grip(?) with MaxValue?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI Slider like the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SliderView: View {

    @State private var sliderVal: Double = 0 // So set this value to 100 is not the answer
    @State var changing = false
    
    var sliderMinValue: Double = 0 // This value varies with some condition
    var sliderMaxValue: Double = 100 // This value varies with some condition
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Slider(value: $sliderVal,
                   in: sliderMinValue...sliderMaxValue,
                   step: 1,
                   onEditingChanged: { change in
                                        
                        self.changing = change
                
            })
            .padding()
            Text("CurrentValue：\(sliderVal)")
            Text(changing ? "Changing" : "Stopping")
        }
    }
}
```

This code displays a slider which grip(?) is on 0 (sliderMinValue).  I'd like to start slider with grip(?) position on 100 (sliderMaxValue), but I can't find out the way.  How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Slider` starts it value with whatever value you inject into it using the `value` `Binding`.

Currently you initialise `sliderVal` to `0` and pass that into your `Slider`. Simply change the initial value to `sliderMaxValue` and your `Slider` will initially be set to its max value.

```
struct SliderView: View {

  @State private var sliderVal: Double
  @State private var changing = false

  private let sliderMinValue: Double
  private let sliderMaxValue: Double


  init(sliderMinValue: Double, sliderMaxValue: Double) {
    self.sliderMinValue = sliderMinValue
    self.sliderMaxValue = sliderMaxValue
    self._sliderVal = State(initialValue: sliderMaxValue)
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {

      Slider(value: $sliderVal,
             in: sliderMinValue...sliderMaxValue,
             step: 1,
             onEditingChanged: { change in

        self.changing = change

      })
      .padding()
      Text("CurrentValue：\(sliderVal)")
      Text(changing ? "Changing" : "Stopping")
    }
  }
}
```

And make sure that you properly inject the min and max values of your slider:

```
SliderView(sliderMinValue: 5, sliderMaxValue: 50)
```

Comment: Sorry my comment was too late.  My `sliderMaxValue` and `sliderMinValue` varies with some condition.  So setting initial value to 100 is not my question's answer...

Comment: @xanadu6291 check my updated answer. You still simply need to pass the value of `sliderMaxValue` to `sliderValue` in the init

Comment: I still hide something. min/max are published properties with initial values of 0.0/1.0 and updated based on information from the net. With init, this initial value is reflected, and it seems that the update information is not in time.

Comment: I just want to do like `self.horizontalSlider.floatValue = Float(self.horizontalSlider.maxValue)` in StoryBoard.

Comment: @xanadu6291 it seems your actual requirements are completely different than what you've portrayed in your question. There's no published properties in your question. You need to ensure that you have a [mcve] in your question, which actually matches your real requirements. The min/max values updating from outside the view are a different question to your original, where you want to be able to set the value of a slider to the maximum - which my answer achieves already.

Comment: OK, I think I should create another question... Sorry for confusing you...